# Can I use a tag in generating pdf through evopdf?

Tags: c#, evopdf

I'm using EvoPdf v.2.4.0.0. Every time I try to create "a" tag it displays only text of this tag, but href doesn't work. is it possoible to use href converting html to PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converter automatically converts by default all the links from HTML to links in PDF. You can disable the links in PDF with HtmlToPdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.LiveUrlsEnabled property. There is a live example for this feature at http://www.evopdf.com/demo/HTML_to_PDF/URI_Links/Convert_URI_Links_to_PDF.aspx